# How to maintain project and dependency jar versions for Gradle build in property file?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm having a Java project with Gradle. Current working version of build.gradle file is like below:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.myproject'
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    'log4j:log4j:1.2.14'
}
```

Here the version of the project (1.0) and log4j dependency version (1.2.14) are hardcoded in the build file. But I want to avoid this and maintain the versions in a separate properties file, so that the build file need not to be modified for any version number change.
I've created a properties file 'build.properties' having content as below:

```
VERSION_NUMBER = '1.0'
LOG4J_VERSION = '1.2.14'
```

and tried to use the property values in build.gradle as below

```
version = VERSION_NUMBER

dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:LOG4J_VERSION'
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

How can I refer the properties file from build.gradle and use the defined properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) file in the root of the project. Gradle will automatically load/use this file to reference properties.

```
# gradle.properties

version=1.0
LOG4J_VERSION=1.2.14
```

Version will automatically be `1.0` because of the `version` property defined. As for log4j, you need to reference it like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "log4j:log4j:$LOG4J_VERSION"
}
```